# Failed to log out SAML WSO2 IS 5.0

Tags: simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

I'm using simpleSAMLphp with SAML(WSO2 IS 5.0) to login in my application, if I try log out after 60 minutes this error is shown:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-12-02 11:10:36,346] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} -  No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2014-12-02 11:10:36,438] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve}
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.String.replace(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendResponse(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleLogoutReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:579)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:91)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

If try with less of 15 minutes it works fine!

I tried change the Identity.xml file here (3600 to 36000):

```
<SSOService>
    <SessionTimeout>36000</SessionTimeout> <!-- remember me session timeout in seconds -->
</SSOService>
```

But the session was not updated with this value after restart the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes..  this is known issue in Identity Server 5.0.0 fresh build.  In identity server does not persist the SSO session.  It just kept in the cache that would be invalidated in 15min. As you are trying to logout after 60 minutes,  so you could see this error. There is no worth of updating the `SessionTimeout` value. You can find the public jira from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2588). This already has been fixed now and would be available with next release.