# WSO2IS: SSO session timeout doesn't work

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently using WSO2 Identity server along with several service providers. I have also configured Single sign on between them.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Configuring+SSO+Session+Timeout) a system admin can configure a validity in seconds for any SSO sessions under /repository/conf/identity.xml, so that an user can enter their credentials, tick "remember me", and log-in to any service provider while the session is still valid. However, changing this value doesn't seem to have any effect. Users can still log-in to the other service provider even when the SSO Session has supposedly expired.

Searching a bit more threw [this JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2118) on WSO2 Oxygen Tank, describing exactly the same problem and has a patch that calls setMaxAge on the "Remember me" cookie, but this hasn't fixed the issue.

Furthermore, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250697/failed-to-log-out-saml-wso2-is-5-0) sessions in memory must be persisted after 15 minutes, and the persistence doesn't work properly. There are a few patches. Yet still, when I try a value of, say, 30 seconds, I can still log-in on another service provider after the SSO session has supposedly expired, so I don't think it's a persistence issue since the session is still on the cache.

How exactly is the session expired on the identity server? Does it send LogoutRequests to every configured service provider on timeout, or is the expiration only valid for new sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How exactly is the session expired on the identity server?*

By default Identity Server 5.0 have session for 15mins and it only can reduce the time using the `web.xml` (which is at `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/` folder)

If you installed `Service Pack 1` for the Identity Server 5.0, it have the session persistence as well. So using that
Identity Server's session timeout can be increased as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence).

*Does it send LogoutRequests to every configured service provider on timeout, or is the expiration only valid for new sessions?*

Identity Server session timeout only valid for new sessions, and it does not send any LogoutRequests to service providers to invalidate existing Service Providers' sessions.